# Issue with typed.js

Tags: jquery, html, css, typed.js

Trying to implement typed.js as a feature in my basic webpage, however, I am having a few issues. I have moved the typed.js file into my file structure -  `js/typed.js`.

I'm sure this is a very simple issue, which I simply can't figure out.  A nod in the right direction would be appreciated.

html

```
<h1 id="mainTitle">Hello World</h1>
<p id="subTitle"></p>
```

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#subTitle").typed({
        strings: [
        "Hello World!"
        "My Name is John"
        ],

        typeSpeed: 70,
        backDelay: 200,
        loop: true
    })
})
```

CSS

```
#subTitle {

  position: absolute;
    color: #F7F2F2;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

Comment: What's the question? You haven't said what the issue is

Comment: maybe you should tell us what the issue is

Comment: I can't implement the typed.js plugin... Nothing comes up.

Comment: Can you provide your entire HTML? You don't show you loading it in something like a script element. `<script src="path/typed.js"></script>`. As well, your path will depend on you file hierarchy. Namely where the html file is located relative to the `typed.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

```
 strings: [
    "Hello World!"
    "My Name is John"
    ],
```

your sintax is wrong. Replace to

```
 strings: [
    "Hello World!",
    "My Name is John"
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

I used `span` tag and remove the `h2 and p tag` and also there is a semicolon missing in the script.

If you use `h2 tag` then the cursor will not display properly.It will be displayed below of the text. I am not 100% sure it will work or not when using h2 tag because I tried and the cursor is displaying below. check in the example.

Check out the output if use h2 tag it will display the cursor below.

https://codepen.io/Narendra_verma/pen/POXPgW

if use the `span` tag.

https://codepen.io/Narendra_verma/pen/EbGVzM

```
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<span id="mainTitle"></span>

<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/typed.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $("#mainTitle").typed({
        strings: ["Hello World!", "My Name is John"],
        typeSpeed: 110, // typing speed
        backDelay: 500, // pause before backspacing
        loop: true,
      });
  });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No joy I'm afraid.  Have you used typed.js before?

Comment: Yes, I just before in my project. it was working and above code is also working